# How do I check if a number is greater than another number, then store it as a variable

Tags: python

I have the python code that asks the question about the users age, but I also need it to check if the user is above 18 and then store if they are 18 or not in a variable.

I have the basic `age = int(input('What is your age?: '))`
set up but now I need it to check if the user is above 18 and then to store a yes or no type of value, as in yes they are above 18 or no that they arent, then I would need to print an acceptance or denial, no if they are not 18 or above and yes if they are.

Comment: Have you tried `age > 18`?

Comment: `above_18 = age > 18`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
accepted = 'yes' if int(input('What is your age?: ')) >= 18 else 'no'
print(accepted)
```

UPDATE (more verbose...as requested)

```
age = int(input('What is your age?: '))
accepted = age >= 18
print('yes' if accepted else 'no')
```

Comment: That seems like it answers the question, but you end up missing the actual value of `age`.

Comment: Which from my gathering of the question is unnecessary

Comment: It could be. It is not clear to me that the actual value of age was important still or not. It seems like it might be but I agree it is not clear. Perhaps you might add a second version of the code that did something to retain that variable.

Comment: Updated as per request. What aren't we all doing for an upvote :D

Comment: `print(f'yes, {age} is ok' if (age := int(input('What is your age?: '))) >= 18 else f'no, {age} is too young')`

Comment: sorry if this question is worded weirdly, im still a little new to python and am learning.